# What parts of the Shabbat shacharit and musaf are omitted when davening without a minyan?

Tags: shabbat, prayer-book, minyan

As I write this, many Jews around the world have just concluded their second consecutive Shabbat since the COVID-19 outbreak led to the temporary closures of synagogues.  Now that so many of us are davening without a minyan, I thought it would be beneficial to list all of the omissions and modifications that apply in this circumstance.

Some of these are fairly easy:  we omit *barchu*, all *kaddishes*, and the repetition of the Amidah. Before reciting *shema* we add the phrase *el melech ne'eman*.  But some are less obvious: for example, when the Torah is not read (because there is no minyan) but one still reads the parsha from a chumash, do we recite *Ein Kamocha* and the other prayers that precede and conclude the Torah reading?  Or do you just go from the end of the Shacharit amidah directly on to musaf?  (Actually, I'm pretty sure that's wrong; my siddur says that one omits the second *yekum purkan* when davening without a minyan, so presumably the first one is read.  But what about *ashrei*, *av harachamim*, etc.?)

The question, then, is: What is the complete list of omissions and modifications made when davening Shabbat morning without a minyan?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** the following is composed for those who use Nusach Ashkenaz and is not complete.

Shacharit

- חצי קדיש
- ברכו
- חזרת הש"ץ
- קדיש שלם
- הוצאת ספר תורה (I would infer that since we omit ﭏ ארך אפים on weekdays without a minyan, that those whose nusach includes אין כמוך באלהים should omit it, although CYLOR)
- My rav has indicated that we should review the פרשת השבוע at this point, although CYLOR
- the second יקום פרקן and the מי־שברך for the קהל
  – הכנסת ספר תורה
- שיר היחוד
- שיר הכבוד